# What is a good name for a character who loves money?

Tags: naming, money

His name is going to be Mr. Price. What should his first name be?

Comment: Welcome to Writers.SE! I'm sorry; Writers.SE doesn't accept questions which ask the community to make story choices for writers. We handle Q&A, but this type of question has no "good" or "bad" answers, only arbitrary opinions, and it is so specific it will not be useful to other users. If you'd like to learn more about Writers.SE and what types of questions are appropriate here, take a look at our [site tour](http://writers.stackexchange.com/tour) and our [on-topic summary](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/875/writers-se-on-topic-summary).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a brainstorming/"what-should I write" question.

Comment: Did his parents already knew he would grow up to be a capitalist? Unless you want your character to be a parody, too obvious names are really stretching the suspension of disbelieve (Nicknames they acquired *because* of their main character traits are of course an exception).

Comment: I'd avoid giving characters names that too obviously describe them, unless the story is intended to be a comedy or a very blatant allegory. In real life, greedy people are not all named "Mr Cash", violent people are not all named "Mr Fist", etc., and seeing names like that in a story just seems ... silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Characters really ought to be multifaceted.  If the last name is "Price" exposing a facet of his personality, then the first name should be random (exposing nothing else) or about another characteristic.  Say, for instance he is loose with is money, "Lax Price" or tight "Hardy Price" or, perhaps, inconsiderate of the value "Shorty Price".

Now, going a non-money relationship, perhaps he's conniving and you want to be obtuse going off of "machinate" and call him, "Mack Price"... That's how I go about doing names... innuendo, abbreviation, and oftentimes reference to the latin/Greek/origin of the word -- Meet "Ergo Lars" (derived from "ergo" and "dol-lars"). ;)

Hope that helps!